# Why are xmlns="" added to element in Java automatically?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces

I am creating an XML file using Java.
I created root node using createElemenNS() to createh root node with namespace.

```
Element root = doc.createElementNS("http://www.myorc.com/schemas", "InvConf");
```

Then I created a node using createElement() and added it to root node. This node is automatically added with namespace like below.

```
 Element invList = doc.createElement("InvList");
 root.appendChild(invList);

<InvConf xmlns="http://www.myorc.com/schemas">
   <InvList xmlns="">
   ...
   </InvList>
   <InvList xmlns="">
   ...
   </InvList>
   <InvList xmlns="">
   ...
   </InvList>
</InvConf>
```

How to avoid adding the namespace to child nodes ?
I want the final XML to be like the following

```
<InvConf xmlns="http://www.myorc.com/schemas">
   <InvList>
   ...
   </InvList>
   <InvList>
   ...
   </InvList>
   <InvList>
   ...
   </InvList>
</InvConf>
```

Found that issues is coming only when xmlparserv2.jar is in CLASSPATH. This is required by some parts for the application. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Child nodes will not have namespace listed if it is in the same namespace as the parent node.

Comment: xmlns="" doesn't add a namespace, it removes one. It's been put there because you created an element that isn't in the same namespace as its parent.

Answer (score 1):

The xmlns="" were added because your child is not in a namespace, and your parent is. To change that, put it in the namespace at the time you create the element.
Change the

```
createElement("InvList");
```

To the correct namespace.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments `xmlns=""` means that element doesn't have any namespace. E.g. from XML parser point of view following two documents are identical:

```
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://namespace.com">
    <child/>
</ns:root>
```

and

```
<root xmlns="http://namespace.com">
    <child xmlns=""/>
</root>
```

To avoid creation of `xmlns=""` in elements not belonging to any namespace you can create prefix on upper level element:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    
Document doc = db.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.com", "root");
root.setPrefix("ns");
Element child = doc.createElementNS("", "child");
root.appendChild(child);
doc.appendChild(root);
```

This code will create following XML:

```
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://namespace.com">
    <child/>
</ns:root>
```

Alternatively you can use following syntax to achieve same result:

```
Document doc = db.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.com", "ns:root");
Element child = doc.createElementNS("", "child");
root.appendChild(child);
doc.appendChild(root);
```

When commenting out line `root.setPrefix("ns");` or creating element without prefix (`doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.com", "root");`) following XML will be generated:

```
<root xmlns="http://namespace.com">
    <child xmlns=""/>
</root>
```

Comment: Shouldn't child element inherit the parent's namespace? Why do we need to explicitly mention it ?

Comment: That's exactly the case. You declare default namespace (namespace without prefix) for parent and by default all children should belong to the same namespace. If they don't, `xmlns=""` is generated to show that they don't belong to parent's namespace.

Comment: Okay. How to avoid adding the xmlns="" to child elements. The final XML should not have this on the child elements.

Comment: That depends. If child elements should be in the same namespace as parent, create them in the same way using `createElementNS()` ans parents namespace. If they shouldn't have namespace, define namespace prefix on parent level as described in the answer.